# Dell Vostro 3400 reboots instead of shutting down

Tags: 11.04, power-management, shutdown, acpi

Well the title says it all. After the GUI button of shutdown responded to reboot. I have tried all the command there is but every time I shut down my laptop it reboots.

I tried

`sudo halt`

`sudo poweroff`

`sudo shutdown -h now`

I have a dell vostro 3400 with i3 and 4 GB RAM if that matters. Has anyone faced this problem. It was doing fine with 10.10

EDIT: Ok, seems like I can confine the problem to prevail during laptop usage from AC only rather than battery. As suggested I tried updating bios with the help of [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DellBIOS) but couldnot succeed.

Comment: Have you checked the BIOS options?

Comment: yes I have and usually this happens when I use ubuntu for more than an hour or so. It would be behaving normally on shutdown during quick use but doesnot halt after a long run

Comment: I would check for a BIOS update from Dell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the problem seems to be `laptop-mode-tools`. I purged this package and viola all is well and I think after installing this package the problem started.